# How to modify post response in php

Tags: php

How to modify this response

```
$url = "https://example.com";
$data = "{\"phone_number\":\"18868768"};
$len = strlen($data);
$headers = array();
$otp = request($url, $data, $headers);
```

the response is

```
{"status":0,"msg":"not Found"}
```

I want to modify to this :

```
{"status":1,"msg":"Found"}
```

Comment: Don't create JSON with string operations. Create an array and use `json_encode()`. `$data =json_encode(['phone_number' => "1886878"]);`

Comment: I don't understand the question at all. The code you posted doesn't have `status` or `msg` anywhere, it doesn't seem related to the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you're saving your response to a `$response` variable. You need to convert the JSON to an array to manipulate it, then convert it back to JSON. So to change it you would do:

```
$response = json_decode($response, true);
$response['status'] = 1;
$response['msg'] = 'Found';
$response = json_encode($response);
```

That being said, you really shouldn't be encoding your initial JSON in string form. Do this instead:

```
$data = json_encode([
    'phone_number' => 18868768
]);
```